# How to use a multi-layer map with countries and lakes with Highmaps?

Tags: highcharts, layer

Is there any way to use a multi-layer map in Highcharts? In my case, I need three layers: One for the countries, one for the borders (which show the disputed ones differently than the normal ones) and one for the lakes, like this:

[image]

In the moment, I don't see how this could be achieved. Or can I export the three layers from shapefile to JSON and then stick the three together? But would a »join« in order to color the countries still work?

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Have you already checked this official demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mapline-mappoint ? I think that shows features similar to your requirements.

Comment: Ah, wow, great example. Thanks a lot. However, I don't succeed in loading the additional map. No idea why. I just replaced the [code here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/xogw9sqt/3/) from [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/19u2xtkc/3/) with the correct JSON, but it doesn't display anything. It should display the country borders. Any idea what is wrong with that?

Comment: I am afraid that the demo which you have shared doesn't work.

Comment: Oups, sorry. Some fiddles disappeared... [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/apsyocmh/4/) is the test with a lake-layer, where I just replaced the JSON from [this working example](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/d5sg4zew/).

Comment: Setting the geometry as a null creates errors (check the console). Try to assign it as an object with empty coordinates array. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06xvrs8m/1/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel: Thanks so much! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Yeah, sure it could be useful for other users which will face a similiar issue in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments - something, like is required on the image, can be done by base on this official demo: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mapline-mappoint

After some attempts, @luftikus143 face into the issue that geometry can't be set as null in his custom JSON file and my solution is to assign it as an object with the empty coordinates array. Demo: jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/06xvrs8m/1

```
{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          type: 'polygon',
          "coordinates": [
            [

            ]
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "OBJECTID": 1,
          "NAME": "Great Bear Lake",
          "Shape_Leng": 35.7525061159,
          "Shape_Area": 6.12829979344
        }
      },
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for that! But having yet another problem with an additional layer. The JSON displays fine in QGIS. But won't be displayed in Highmaps ([here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/9h1L3zq7/5/)). It's a multiline layer, with just a couple of lines. It has the geometry defined as above. I tried out different files, all line-type, but didn't succeed. What is wrong with that?

Comment: Take a look at this demo it should help you to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/geojson-multiple-types and wanted output: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yg2fbpm3/

Comment: Great, that's perfect. For better understanding: Why do I use once `mapData: Highcharts.maps['lakes'],` and once `data: Highcharts.geojson(Highcharts.maps['customMap'], 'mapline')`? What is the logic behind that? Or can both written the other way around as well?

Comment: @luftikus143 their data type is different. `Highcharts.maps` can read the `Polygon` or `MultiPolygon` types, but if you use others you need to parse them by using Highcharts.geojson feature.